Using a Casio keyboard as midi controller for Grandorgue
My Casio CPS-101 has midi in/out/thru traditional 5-pin connections but has no (apparent) means of switching from 'normal' play mode to midi.  I imagine access must be though a combination of selection buttons and keys.  I have used my Clavinova successfully as a midi keyboard and that was straightforward.  Any assistance regarding the Casio midi would be appreciated.

What is "normal play mode"? What happens right now when you try? What are you hoping for that's different? please clarify.

Thank you for your reply. Up 'til now I have used the Yamaha Clavinova as a midi keyboard and had to alter settings using function keys, the computer then recognised the midi information.  I expected to have to go though a similar procedure with the CSP-101 (I had no manual to consult).  Having now seen the manual I now see the errors of my ways and all is now clear.  Thank you for your help.

When you play a midi device, midi out is enabled automatically. It's possible to change the midi channel, which is generally designed to be at ch 1 automatically. There is no need to have the volume of the motherboard up, it can be used as simply a motherboard, feeding the midi signal to whatever other midi device is connected, obviously from midi out to midi in using that 5pin din.
If all else fails, read the instructions!
Set 'local control' to 'off'. According to user manual, that enables the 'board to become the controller.

Thank you for the helpful advice.  Having now seen the manual with the relevant midi explanations I see where my initial assumptions were wrong.  Coming from using a Clavinova the setting up differs.  The channel selection is interesting and will be useful when I set up a second manual.  Thank you for your help.

I don't think you need to switch anything.  Hit the keys, MIDI comes out.  If you turn the volume up, sound comes out as well. If not, not.
But there are some settings.   Pages 11-12-13 of the manual.  If you've lost yours, here it is:
CPS-101 manual

Ahh.  I see now what I should be looking for.  I did not have a manual but thought some combinations of buttons/keys would be required.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.
